# Integral of a function under a square root

Tags: calculus

I need to solve $$\int_0^t\sqrt{20u^2 + 9u^4} du$$

This is a problem from a textbook I am using for practice.
I have a good understanding of everything through Calc BC.
I know a substitution has to be made, but I never learned how to deal with square roots.

Comment: Completing the square and reducing to "well-known" integrals of type $\int\sqrt{1\pm x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x,\int\sqrt{x^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is generally the way to go (the same goes for $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cdots}}$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factor a $u^2$ to get $$\int_0^t\sqrt{20u^2+9u^4}du=\int_0^tu\sqrt{20+9u^2}du$$Let $v=20+9u^2$, then $dv=18u$: $$\int_0^tu\sqrt{20+9u^2}du=\frac{1}{18}\int^{20+t^2}_{20}\sqrt{v}dv=\frac{1}{27}v^\frac{3}{2}\bigg|_{20}^{20+9t^2}=\frac{1}{27}\left((20+9t^2)^\frac{3}{2}-20^\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Unless $t$ is negative.